# Action of the Alternating Group on the Riemann Sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on the Riemann sphere. Using Hurwitz' formula, it can be easily seen that the quotient map $\pi: G \to $ there could be two or three branch points. The case of two branches gives rise to a cyclic group. If we have three branches, four cases occur. One of them is the case $|G|=12$ (order of $G$ is $12$). 
Miranda (Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces) says that in this case $G=A_4$. So, my question is: how is it possible to define an action of $A_4$ on the Riemann sphere?

Using the presentation $\langle r,t: \, r^3=t^3=(rt)^2=1 \rangle$, I have to find two maps $r,t$ on $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ having order $3$ and whose composition has order $2$. I have no clue.

Comment: The group of oriented symmetries of a regular tetrahedron is $A_4$.

Comment: @Travis I'm searching for the analytic expression of the maps. In fact, in the case of the dihedral group, Miranda finds the analytic expressions of the maps generating the dihedral groups, namely $f(z)=e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{r}}z$ and $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. Which is the analytic expression for the generators of the alternating group $A_4$?

Comment: The problem is to write down the vertices of the regular tetrahedron on the Riemann sphere. The two generators $r,t$ are rotations that fix one of these points and cyclically permute the other three. There will be a unique Mobius map which does that. Then the other transformations can be computed by composition.

Comment: @Nick L I found on Wikipedia which are the coordinates of the vertices of a tetrahedron. I can use stereographic projection to pass to $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ and then I consider the Moebius transformation fixing one of them and permuting the others.

Comment: @TheWanderer I encourage you to write up your solution as an answer here, for posterity.

Comment: A nice proof of the classification of the finite subgroups of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is given in http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/McKaybook.pdf

Another nice exposition is given in https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/McKay/Carrasco_Project.pdf
where the polyhedra is taken into account. 

The classic reference is Coxeter's book "Regular Complex Polytopes"